# Neo4j: Error for relationship property: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#__relationship_connecting_node_entities I want to save nodes that have a 1:1 relation to another complex node. Used Neo4j version: 3.2.6

Following use case:

- For uploaded files specific information about these files are stored into Neo4j as an entity of `FileHashEntity`
- Users who are uploading files are present as user objects in Neo4j: `BaseUserEntity` and `UserEntity`
- `FileHashEntity` has a relationship to the user who originally uploaded the file the first time

The Java classes that specify the user objects are declared as following:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class BaseUserEntity {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
...
}

public class UserEntity extends BaseUserEntity {

    @Id
    private String email;

    private String passwordHash;
...
}
```

And the entity for the file information looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class FileHashEntity {
    @DateLong
    private Date creationTime;

    @Id
    private String sha256;

...

    private long size;

    @Relationship(type = "UPLOADED_BY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private UserEntity uploader;
...
}
```

If I try to store the `FileHashEntity` I receive an error due to the complex object property (`UserEntity`):

```
public interface FileHashRepository extends Neo4jRepository<FileHashEntity, String> {

    @Query(value = "merge (n:FileHashEntity {sha256: {0}}) on create set n = {1} return n")
    FileHashEntity storeIfNotExists(String sha256, FileHashEntity entity);
...
}

Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:76)
```

But the Spring documentation states that this should be possible even without explicit `@Relationship` annotation (see link above). I even tried to replace the declaration type `UserEntity` by `BaseUserEntity`. What's wrong?

Comment: It has something to do with the query in the ``FileHashRepository`` class. I don't make a usual "save" operation, but a "merge on create" which means: "insert if not exists". The final query sets each property of ``n`` and for the ``UserEntity`` property it sets the entire object.

Usual "save" works fine. But I need "save if not exists"!!!

Comment: Another approach would be to check the existence in the service method first, and then save eventually. Spring Data's ``@Transactional`` annotation has an ``isolation`` attribute. Unfortunately, ``Neo4jTransactionManager`` doesn't allow other isolation settings than default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109292/how-to-manually-manage-neo4j-locks-in-spring-managed-transaction Also see ``doBegin()`` method: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/transaction/Neo4jTransactionManager.java

Comment: Did you resolve this? Can you pls share your finding ?